# Google Play - check which store listing language version the app was downloaded from

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish an app in two languages - English and Polish. **I know how to check user's phone language settings to localize my app, but I was wondering what to do in this situation:**

I'm Polish but my phone is in English. I go to Google Play and type in Polish "hiszpański" (Spanish), looking for an app to learn Spanish. I download the app from the Polish-version store listing, but if the app is using a device language, I will see the app in English.

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent that from happening, and check which store listing language was used to download the app. Are there any best practices around this? Thank you!